# $http.get() returns blank data in AngularJS from external source

Tags: json, angularjs, http

I tried to fetch data from external sources in Angular JS via $http but it returns blank data. The same service when used to fetch data from a local file works perfect.

**The code for fetching data from local source:**

```
controllers.controller('listController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope,$http) {

    var data = null;

     $http.get('js/test.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.markers = data.hooks;

        });

          $scope.map = {
            center: {
                latitude: 45,
                longitude: -73
            },
            zoom: 2
        };

  }]);
```

**The code for fetching data from an external source:**

```
  controllers.controller('listController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope,$http) {

      var data = null;

       $http.get('http://115.113.151.200:8081/user/maphook/mobile/generate_list.jsp').success(function(data) {
              $scope.markers = data.hooks;          
          });

            $scope.map = {
              center: {
                  latitude: 45,
                  longitude: -73
              },
              zoom: 2
          };            
    }]);
```

As you can see just the url has changed, in the latter case firebug happens to show the following in the console:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBNeh.png)

I'm not sure what is wrong. I use the json data to plot points on a google map. The test.json works perfectly. I'm assuming it could either be that external sources of data (domain different than the current) are not allowed, or the Angular goes on to render the google map even before the data is returned from the external source.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the external server doesn't allows you to request data. 
There is a whole standard shaping this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 0):

You should read on JSONP if you intend to use ajax cross-domain to send and receive json data. It is supported in angular.js, you just need to find an example (Google has loads).

Jsonp is what you need.